# What can I do to get better traffic/responses to my questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, question-quality

I'm having particular difficulty getting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24518226/on-ubuntu-finding-it-impossible-to-install-setup-javax-usb-libusb1) question answered. In this instance I've actually been downvoted 1 (though likely just as it's basically a carbon copy of a question I'd asked before). My problem is that I have limited experience with this particular facet that I now find myself forced to deal with. Anyway, how can I better phrase a question/issue like this that I might receive the help I need to find the answer/solve the problem (in this case, build the stupid library)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was your first title: "Trying to compile javax-usb-libusb1 gives an error:" - that's it, no error included, just the observation that there *was* an error (which you listed further on down).

This was your second: "On Ubuntu, finding it impossible to install/setup JavaX-USB-LibUSB1"

Not exactly geared toward catching the eye of anyone who *might* actually know something about the problem you're encountering, eh?

You also had a lot of... Cruft... in your question. Oh, and as you noted, you posted *two* questions about the same problem. You could've just edited the first one. You *should've* just edited the first one.

I've edited the title and removed a bit of the cruft. Not saying it'll help (for all I know, you may be the first and only person to ever encounter this exact situation), but something to learn from in the future.

Comment: thank you thank you thank you. my only hope is to learn and grow... what is "cruft"?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Acruft

Comment: thanks again. I was only trying to show I'm not looking for a handout, that I really feel I've done everything within my limited capacity to resolve this issue.

Comment: @Shog9 do I need to flag that for moderator attention as a LMGTFY link?

Comment: Does it link to lmgtfy.com, @Cupcake?

Comment: @Shog9 I see that I failed miserably at my attempt for humor `:/`

Comment: [No fun allowed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262196/which-tagfun-questions-are-on-topic), @Cupcake.