# Which [tag:fun] questions are on topic?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

Which [fun](/questions/tagged/fun) questions are on topic. I posted a [fun](/questions/tagged/fun) question<sup><sub>*</sub></sup>, and it was immediately destroyed. I was given a reason for why it wasn't on topic, but which ones *are*?

---

<sub><sup>*</sup>Although to tell the truth, my Emacs vs Vi question did have a 27% chance of enrapturing the stack overflow community and causing small riots in related exchanges.</sub>

Answer (score 5):

"Fun" does not mean you can just come post *any* question that you think is fun. They still have to be on-topic for Meta, meaning they have to be *about* Stack Overflow in some way. Your question had absolutely nothing to do with Stack Overflow - it was just an opinion poll about which editor people liked.

Past that, a question which is solely fun is usually going to get closed down. The question still needs to have a definitive purpose, meaning that there is a problem that needs to be solved. The [fun](/questions/tagged/fun) tag itself is generally applied to indicate that there is a humorous or joking tone to the problem being described in the question, and could easily be described as a meta-tag since it doesn't really cover any formal topic.

I've copied over the excerpt from Meta Stack Exchange to give the tag a little description:

> Questions that are light-hearted but hopefully of some additional use beyond mere entertainment.