# Should there be a "fun" tag on meta?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, meta

I just wanted to celebrate my 365th day in a row on Stack Overflow. By starting a "discussion" about how many years other people have on the "clock". But since I know that there are other people here that might think it is inappropriate to do so, I wanted to assure myself that it is appropriate to do this.

After some research on Meta and the help center, it seems like it is not. At the same time I thought it would be fun to have the opportunity to interact with people on Meta with less serious matters as usual. I know this from other forums as well and there seems to be some attempts for similar "events", like [the 10.000.000 question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302884/10-000-000th-question-is-here) or [1 mio reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403218/congratulations-vonc-for-reaching-a-million-reputation) on Stack Exchange. However, they get locked or closed with as [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta).

I guess [there was a time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262196/which-tagfun-questions-are-on-topic) where something like a [fun](/questions/tagged/fun) existed, but I didn't find a post explaining why this tag was removed. So my question to the community is, do we want or need such a tag? Wouldn't y'all at least agree to "it would strengthen the community"?

Comment: Use chat instead.

Comment: Nope. Sorry, but **this isn’t a forum**. And if you have to *label* fun then… you were doing it wrong.

Comment: @MartijnPieters congratulations to your 1 mio points, by the way. :D

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'll agree that the main site is not, but meta is a forum for discussion.

Comment: There's already a [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122976/anyone-with-a-visited-4444-days-4444-consecutive-in-their-profile) about the consecutive visits on MSE

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat thanks for making me aware of it. I might join this thread as well. :)

Comment: No. On Stack Overflow [we hate fun](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/)

Comment: @TadeuszKopecforUkraine that's not about meta, it is about the main site.

Comment: [Only on](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158615/the-moderators-have-decided-to-have-a-little-yuletide-fun-join-us-will-you) [Fridays](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/21413#21413).

Answer (score 8):

Congrats on your consecutive accessing the site over the last year!

For real though, this isn't a thing because Meta Stack Overflow isn't a forum.

If you want to goof off a bit, you can always join chat. The chatrooms tend to be more open to this sort of thing.

Comment: While the main site tend to be not to, meta is a forum or does "forum" mean something different on [so] as the definition on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_forum) ?