# What can I do to get responses to my question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, question-quality

I have asked a question, *[Opening a Java file in an active working set instead of class file in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44839379/1083581)*.
This meta question is not a duplicate of *[What can I do to get better traffic/responses to my questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262195/1083581)* as I believe I have incorporated everything from the accepted answer. I have even put a bounty on my question, and it still didn't get a lot of views (and hence answers).

What can I do to get more views to my question?

Comment: [questionception] needs to be a thing.

Comment: @psubsee2003 updated tag

Comment: Downvote ? Care to explain ?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but have you taken a look at the suggestions that popped up when you entered the question title? E.g. [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326823/unanswered-questions-what-am-i-still-missing-and-what-can-i-do-to-improve-them), whose accepted answer *may* fit your case exactly, judging from a quick look.

Answer (score 0):

- Assign a larger bounty.
- Edit your title to be clearer.
- Edit your question to be clearer / easier to answer.
- Make sure your question is tagged properly.
- Make sure your question uses the common terminology people use for the topic to make it easier for people to find it by searching.
- Link to your question on Twitter.
- Start a Google AdWords campaign.
- Create a flyer to distribute at your place of work.

Seriously, though. Bounties are pretty much the only built-in tool for getting your question more attention.